# How to format string in a contract

Tags: smart-contract, boost

I'm trying to format string using boost library, but EOS gives error `<atomic> is not supported on this single threaded system`. But, as for me, boost format is the most convenient solution. Anybody know any convenient solutions for string formatting?

Comment: what are trying to achieve? can you give an example?

Comment: Please share you code so that we can know what you are doing wrong. Not the whole code but the main part inwhich you have doubts.....